# adding index for an attribute of jsonb field in elasticsearch rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

I am a beginner in elasticsearch and I want to add an index for the field inside a jsonb field I am having. This is not a nested relationship.

I am having table payload with fields `id` (integer),`user_id`(integer),`data`(jsonb).

Sample jsonb value is like:

```
{"name" => "Test User", "values" => {"age" => 24, "gender" => "male"}, "married": false}
```

I want to add index for the "gender" field inside "values" section of "data"(jsonb column).

Database is postgres.

I have added the index configuration as follows:

```
  mappings do
    indexes :id,      type: 'integer'
    indexes :user_id, type: 'integer'

    indexes :data do
      indexes :gender
    end
  end
```

Is this right?

I am getting exact results for the query,

```
{"query": {
    "term": {
        "user_id": 1
    }
}}
```

but not for this query

```
{"query": {
    "term": {
        "gender": "male"
    }
}}
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Looks like this one might help you here: http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-4-feature-highlight-indexing-jsonb/

Comment: @TarynEast.. Thanks..I have edited the question. I am looking for adding index in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 3):

I use `nested` type to define the jsonb object:

```
  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :id, type: 'integer'
      indexes :user_id, type: 'integer'
      indexes :name, type: 'text'
      indexes :data, type: 'nested' do
        indexes :gender, type: 'text'
        indexes :age, type: 'integer'
      end
    end
  end
```

Read here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html for more information about JSON documents.

If you have dynamic fields in the JSONB objects then you can define the index like this:

```
  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :id, type: 'integer'
      indexes :user_id, type: 'integer'
      indexes :name, type: 'text'
      indexes :data, dynamic: 'true' do
      end
    end
  end
```